# How to do Fourier analysis for both temporal and spatial frequencies

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series, fourier-transform, signal-processing, fast-fourier-transform

Given a time-and-space-dependent signal like the following:

$$F(z,t) = \dfrac{a_0}{2} + \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} [a_n \cos(k_n z + w_n t + \phi_n)].$$

How do I extract both the *temporal* and *spatial* frequency components of this signal, i.e., $(a_n, k_n, w_n, \phi_n)$?

I am not sure what sort of Fourier transform could apply in this case. If someone can also suggest a python package that helps to do this task, that will be appreciated.

Comment: As it is written, your question is hard to understand. If you have such an equation, can't you just read off the frequency components?

Comment: @AnonSubmitter85 Hi, I have the data for it not the equation that produces the data.

Comment: What is the format of your data? Is it a 2-D array with space in one dimension and time in the other? The more information you can provide and the more specific you can be, the more likely you are to get help.

Comment: @AnonSubmitter85 Exactly, it is a 2-D array where one dimension represents the time(t) and one the position(z). I corrected the formula in the question to be f(z,t)

Comment: Taking the DFT in the time dimension will yield the temporal frequency and taking the DFT in the spatial dimension will yield the spatial frequency.